# Is it possible to do this with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using Facebook's Graph API, I am currently looping through all friends to retrieve their videos, and then present a list of these videos to the user. It obviusly takes a while to do this depending on number of friends,

Is there any way to just say to FQL - give me all videos that I have permsission to view?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't want applications to be able to "mine data".  They don't want applications to be able to collect that much data on anything they want.  In most cases an ID must be specified.

- User ID
- Page ID
- Group ID
- Event ID
- etc...

Even in such a case there is also limitations and multiple calls will have to be made.  The limitations themselves are not only limited to accessing data with FQL or the Graph API.
There are also limitations on your access to the API.  This is called application throttling and it can be enforced on your application if they find you doing an abnormally large amount of calls to the API.  There are also other limitations such as making multiple sequential posts or even duplicate posts to your users.

I'm afraid that the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with the graph API explorer:

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20vid%2C%20owner%2C%20title%2C%20src%20FROM%20video%20WHERE%20owner%3Dme%28%29`

I know that to get a list of my friends I can do:

`SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()`

I then updated the video query to:

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20vid%2C%20owner%2C%20title%2C%20src%20FROM%20video%20WHERE%20owner%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29%29`

And now I get a paginated list of all videos belonging to my friends.   This one query is certainly better than pounding the API to death with multiple calls.  :)